# Select multiple columns and paste them into sheet1 of new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select multiple columns by the column header in an Excel sheet, then copy these columns into a new workbook.

With the code below, Excel opens one book per column instead of pasting all of the selected columns into sheet1 of the new workbook.

I recorded a macro for this task, but the column header changes every time so I cannot depend on recorded macros.

```vb
Sub Colheadr()
    Dim wsO As Worksheet
    'Dim wsF As Worksheet....I comment out this line
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsO = ActiveSheet
    'Set wsF = Worksheets("Final").....I comment out this line
    myColumns = Array("Facility", "Last Name", "First Name", "MRN", "adm date")
    With wsO.Range("A1:W1")
        For i = 0 To UBound(myColumns)
            On Error Resume Next
           .Find(myColumns(i)).EntireColumn.Copy
            Workbook.Add
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            'Destination:=wsF.Cells(1, i + 1)...I comment out this line
            Err.Clear
        Next i
    End With
    Set wsO = Nothing
    Set wsF = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Public Sub CopyBetweenBooks()
    Dim myCollection    As Collection
    Dim myIterator      As Variant
    Dim myRng           As Range
    Dim xlcell          As Variant
    Dim otherwb         As Workbook
    Dim mywb            As Workbook
    Dim colCounter      As Integer

    Set mywb = ThisWorkbook
    Set myCollection = New Collection

    'Create a collection of header names to search through
    myCollection.Add ("Header1")
    myCollection.Add ("Header2")
    myCollection.Add ("Header3")

    'Where to search, this is the header
    Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:W1")
    Set otherwb = Workbooks.Add
    colCounter = 0
    For Each xlcell In myRng.Cells ' look through each cell in your header
        For Each myIterator In myCollection ' look in each item in the collection
            If myIterator = xlcell.Value Then ' when the header matches what you are looking for
                colCounter = colCounter + 1 ' creating a column index for the new workbook
                mywb.ActiveSheet.Columns(xlcell.Column).Copy
                otherwb.ActiveSheet.Columns(colCounter).Select
                otherwb.ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan, this works as i want, the only thing is i forgot to mention in my post that i am trying to also arrange the headers in a specific order, that was why i was using MyColOrder=Array in my initial code. Is there anyway i can still insert Array method into this code you provided i have tried myCollection= Array ("#", "Header1", "Header2"' etc) but it did not work.Thank you.

Comment: You can use an array instead if you prefer. To loop through an array, use something like: for i = LBound(myarr) to UBound(myArr) instead of the for each myIterator. Also, you can simply add the item in the collection in the same order you want them pasted. The order will be retained.

Comment: Ok i will try the for loop and see. i actually added the item in the collection in the same order i want it, but it did not work that way, instead it pasted them in the order in which they appear in the original workbook. thank you.

Comment: Hi Ryan, so i've been silent because i was having a problem in the sense that two particular Columns will not copy no matter what i do, and i did not want to come back and waste your time with some flimsy questions without searching for possible answers first. I remember when i was working as a Doctor in my Country and having to teach Medical Students and them coming with simple questions that they could have gotten answer to by reading. So the Problem was that i needed to add Trim.xlcell.Value after If myIterator =. It took me 2 days to find this though. Thank you so much. Case Marked Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem 3 years later in 2019. Ryan Wildry was right. Instead of collection data type use array to maintain user defined column sequence. That's why I am referring Ryan Wildry's solution with additional lines.

```
Public Sub CopyBetweenBooks()
Dim myCollection(1 To 3)    As String
Dim myIterator      As Variant
Dim myRng           As Range
Dim xlcell          As Variant
Dim otherwb         As Workbook
Dim mywb            As Workbook
Dim colCounter      As Integer

Set mywb = ThisWorkbook


'Create an array of header names to search through
myCollection(1) ="Header1"
myCollection(2) ="Header2"
myCollection(3) ="Header3"

'Where to search, this is the header
Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:W1")
Set otherwb = Workbooks.Add
colCounter = 0

For i = LBound(myCollection) To UBound(myCollection)
 For Each xlcell In myRng.Cells ' look through each cell in your header

        If myCollection(i) = xlcell.Value Then ' when the header matches what you are looking for
            colCounter = colCounter + 1 ' creating a column index for the new workbook
            mywb.ActiveSheet.Columns(xlcell.Column).Copy
            otherwb.ActiveSheet.Columns(colCounter).Select
            otherwb.ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next
 Next
Next
End Sub
```